# CPTScatterPlot connect point with skip some data point

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

For example, from 09:00am to 09:05:am
Ideally, I got 6 points from server for my plot.

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot {
   return 6;
}
```

dataSource

```
Index Time  Price    

0     09:00 84.2
1     09:01 84.5
2     09:02 84.1
3     09:03 84.0
4     09:04 84.1
5     09:05 84.0
```

But, In fact, Server will response data source like this

```
Index Time  Price    
0     09:00 84.2
1     09:01 84.5
2     09:02 nil
3     09:03 nil
4     09:04 84.1
5     09:05 84.0
```

I return 6 for numberOfRecordsForPlot
And nil for numberForPlot index 2 and 3
I will get plot like this
  [image]
My question is 
if index 2 and index 3 no data
How do I connect index 1 to index 4 with a straight line
i.e. connect (1, 84.5) to (4, 84.1) using a straight line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only have four data points to plot, `-numberOfRecordsForPlot:` should return `4`. The datasource should also skip over the `nil` values:

```
Index Time  Price    
0     09:00 84.2
1     09:01 84.5
2     09:04 84.1
3     09:05 84.0
```